# Is there anyway to increase the expiration time of access_token

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are trying to use Forge Viewer in offline mode, but the main blocker for this is, the access_token that was acquired gets expired in an hour. Is there any way to increase the expire time?

Answer (score 0):

In the Forge platform, access tokens are generated with a lifespan of 1 hour and this is non-negotiable. This is for security reasons on Autodesk's end and unfortunately, you can't increase the expiration time.

That said, here are some alternative approaches you can consider that don't involve lengthening the lifespan of your tokens:

1. Implement a token refresh mechanism: Your application could implement a mechanism to routinely renew the access_token just before it expires. However, beware that this won't work in completely offline mode.
2. Use two-legged authentication for Viewer: You can use "Two-legged authentication" with Forge Viewer which can be used in offline mode. Your application would have to handle obtaining and refreshing the tokens, though.
3. Complete extraction of SVF for Offline Viewing: For very specific cases, you can extract the SVF and properties database used by Forge Viewer and set up your offline viewer to be able to load these locally.

Please note that these workarounds come with their own complications and may not work for all scenarios. It's best to analyze your use case and decide which method suits you best.

Comment: Great answer.  Would a shorter token expiry feature be useful to anyone ?